# carousel of html pages showed in a  modal with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, lightbox, carousel

For a project I need to build a carousel of html pages loaded into a modal, like in the example in the image below.

Some other features requested are:

1. partial visibility of previous and next carousel steps ability to
2. force the open of the lightbox with the carousel exactly in one specific step and not always at the first one
3. auto-height of the carousel steps, not a fixed one
4. hide of the prev(next) arrow for the first(last) item

My idea is to treat a single step of the carousel as a single external html page, but I'm open to every suggestion.

So, the question is: what is the best way to make this? [image: I'm looking for plugin and best practictes, in case.]
Thank you so much in advance, any help will be strongly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my personal favorite:

http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/

Works great, highly browser compatible (when done right), and easily customized.

Just lay it over a semi-transparent fixed div and your set.

Comment: very nice plugin @Fluidbyte, so do you suggest not to use any lightbox plugin with this?

Comment: You could ultimately combine it with a lightbox, but given you screenshot/mockup I automatically thought this plugin would be a good fit.

Comment: ok thanks @Fluidbyte, I accept your answer. Vote for my question if you believe, thank you so much.